# How to test swagger with IFormFile and model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

I've made a webapi. I currently have two endpoints, first endpoint does an httppost that accepts a model. The second is an endpoint that accepts a IFormFile. both endpoint works.

I'm currently trying to make a third endpoint that accepts a model and has an IFormFIle. When I enter swagger, I don't see the choose file option for Request Body

[image]

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Document>> AddOne([FromBody] DocumentAddRequest docAddRequest) {....}

public class DocumentAddRequest
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IFormFile File {get; set;}
}
```

I've also tried adding within the controller but I still don't see the choose file button when entering swagger.

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Document>> AddOne([FromBody] DocumentAddRequest docAddRequest, IFormFile file) {....}
```

May I ask how do I test my endpoint for file upload that also consumes a model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like below, and the issue could be fixed.

```
[HttpPost("AddOne")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Document>> AddOne([FromForm] DocumentAddRequest docAddRequest, IFormFile file) {
    ...
}
```

#### Reason

We should use `multipart/form-data` type data when uploading the model in your scenario, so using [FromForm] attribute can solve this problem.

**Test Result**

[image]

[image]